# How to register for targeted Push Notifications in Azure Mobile App notification hub from iOS

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I have a mobile app that registers for Push Notifications within Azure Mobile App service.
In previous versions (Azure Mobile Services) I could add the Tag on registration. For security reasons this possibility was removed in the current Mobile Apps service.
In another thread in this forum I read that we need to create a custom API to add tags like the user ID for targeted notifications. 
The documentation in Azure only mentions .NET and I need to do it in javascript. So, I wrote this API:

```
module.exports = {
"put": function (req, res, next) {

    var token = req.query.token;
    token = token.replace('<','');
    token = token.replace('>',''); //Removing the token enclosures
    token = token.replace(/\s+/g,''); //Removing the spaces in the token
    req.azureMobile.push.apns.createNativeRegistration(token, req.azureMobile.user.id, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Registration unsuccessful: ", error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: error });
        } else {
            var result = "Registration successful"
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({result: result});
        }
    });
}
}
```

I am calling it from iOS with this Swift code:

```
 self.client!.push?.registerDeviceToken(deviceToken, completion: {(error) in
        var results = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
        if error == nil {
            let param = ["token":deviceToken]
            AOAppDelegate.client!.invokeAPI("apnsRegistration", body: nil, HTTPMethod: "PUT", parameters: param, headers: nil, completion: {(objects, httpResponse, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
        }
    })
```

The process works perfectly fine in my iPhone but not in my iPad and there is nothing wrong specifically with this iPad, which makes me think that the code has something missing.
Also if I go to the notification hub within the Azure Portal, it has 0 tags registered when it should have at least one for the registered iPhone that works fine.
The Test Push notification also send the notification only for the phone and not to the iPad.

Any suggestions? Does my code make sense?

Thanks,

Comment: Check if your test push is broadcast. If yes, then it is the problem with the registrations. It looks like you are using  Mobile App API instead of Notification Hubs. Could you please check that as well? And to check registrations and tags using Service Bus Explorer as well

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex. I have configured a Notifications Hub, but I cannot find any documentation on how to register the tags using the hub from Javascript. Do you know where can I find some information? The code examples in azure are only in .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call doesn't look write.  Try something like:

```
var promises = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/utilities/promises');

function createInstallation(context, installationId, pushChannel) {
    var installation = {
        installationId: installationId,
        pushChannel: pushChannel,
        platform: 'apns',
        tags: [ 'some', 'list' ]
    };

    return promises.wrap(context.push.createOrUpdateInstallation, context.push)(installation);
}

module.exports = {
    post: function (req, res, next) {
        var context = req.azureMobile,
            installationId = req.get('X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID'),
            pushChannel: req.body.pushChannel;

        createInstallation(context, installationId, pushChannel)
        .then((result) => {
          res.status(204).end();
        });
        .catch(next);
    }
}
```

context.push just wraps the Notification Hubs SDK, so you can use anything from there.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. The req.body.pushChannel is assuming that I need to send the pushchannel within the body of the request?

Comment: Correct - send something like { "pushChannel": "<what-you-got-from-pns>" }

Comment: In the client before making the call I have only the Azure installation ID and the deviceToken. I don't have any property or variable called pushChannel available. Where can I get it? Are you referring to the device token?

Comment: The pushChannel is the registrationId that you receive from the PNS. This is not the Azure installation Id (that is generated by the SDK), nor is it the deviceId that you send to the PNS.  It's what you get back from the PNS.  Unfortunately, different PNS call it different things.

Comment: Hi Adrian. I've been checking the documentation and for Apple the PushChannel is the deviceToken. But the code is not working though. I am not even able to send the Test notification from the hub in the portal. The only difference between my code and yours is that first I need to get the email address of the current user from context.user.getIdentities since I am using that as a tag. Any ideas?

Comment: It was just bad timing. I started to test your solution this week, but last Saturday the developer certificate with Apple expired. XCode fixed the issue generating a generic certificate which are not allowed to be used with Push Notifications. As soon as I generated a good certificate your code started working perfectly. Thank you for your help!